# Is it possible to zoom out a plot of a map in R?

Tags: r, cartography

Sometimes a plot looks zoomed in how to arrange that?
i use the rgeos package mainly. When i do a buffer for example somewhere the plot tends to zoom in some part of the map which is not good since it cuts parts even from the buffer too in the plot.

Comment: Could you please supply more details such as what packages you are working with? Including a sample script would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the extent using the `xlim` and `ylim` parameters.

```
library(rgeos)

p1 = readWKT("POLYGON((0 1,0.95 0.31,0.59 -0.81,-0.59 -0.81,-0.95 0.31,0 1))")

par(mfrow = c(1,2))
plot(gBuffer(p1,width=-0.2),col='black',xlim=c(-0.5,1),ylim=c(-0.5,1), xlab="Original")
plot(gBuffer(p1,width=-0.2),col='black',xlim=c(-1,1),ylim=c(-1,1), xlab="Zoomed Out")
```

---

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you used the readWKT (well known text). i read the help but didn't undestand it.Basically if u can add comments of what you did it will help. In the end, you answered succesfully what i was asking .

Comment: Don't worry about that, it is simply used to generate sample data for this example. I borrowed elements from the `rgeos` `gBuffer` documentation for this example.

Comment: Just for learning, can you tell me what readWKT does?

Comment: WKT is simply used for representing vector geometry objects on a map. From the rgeos documentation: "readWKT processes the given WKT string and returns an appropriate sp geometry object".